# Get Difference in Hours/Minutes From Two Date Values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a date value (e.g. 2011-04-11 07:45:00.000) which I am pulling from my database (via Entity Framework). I need to pull out only the hour from the original date value (e.g. 07:45:00), get the current time, and then subtract the current time from the database time value. In pseudo-code, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
Dim my_date as DateTime = from_db ' This is the value pulled from the database.
Dim this_date as DateTime = Date.Now ' This is pulled via a VB.NET function.
Dim my_hour = my_date_but_only_hours ' Somehow, I need to strip the date off the my_date
Dim this_hour = this_date_but_only_hours ' Same as line above.
Dim hour_difference = my_hour - this_hour
Response.Write("There are " & hour_difference & " hours left before the time runs out.")
```

Comment: Are you not going to append the difference in days to the total difference in hours?

Comment: Nope. B/c the days don't matter. It is only used to store the hours...but there doesn't seem to be a neat way to store just hours, e.g. a Time data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dbDate = from_db.TimeOfDay  'This gets you a TimeSpan object representing just the time of day in that date.
```

If you just want the hour, proceed with:

```
dim dbHour = dbDate.Hour
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_date.Subtract(this_date).TotalHours
```

or

```
my_date.TimeOfDay.Subtract(this_date.TimeOfDay).TotalHours
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` to throw away the date component. You can then compute the difference represented as a `TimeSpan`. This gives you access to information about how many hours difference there is:

```
Dim dbTimeOfDay = from_db.TimeOfDay
Dim nowTimeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
Dim timeDifference = dbTimeOfDay - nowTimeOfDay
Dim hoursDifference = timeDifference.TotalHours
```

The variable `hoursDifference` is a `Double` where the minutes and seconds are included in the fraction. You can round it or truncate if that is a requirement.